# pytz package: can only be run with python2 (after pip install pytz) even though python3 is normally used

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-2.x, pytz

When installing pytz to be used in a Python project, I get following Terminal output on my wsl Terminal:

```
pip install pytz
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. 
More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pytz
  Downloading pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 509 kB 1.3 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pytz
Successfully installed pytz-2019.3
```

Afterwards, when running test.py I still got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pytz
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'
```

Trying `import pytz-2019.3` and `pytz2019.3` threw SyntaxErrors.

Finally, I could run the file with: `python2 test.py`.

I am wondering (for this package and for other packages which yield to similar problems) how I could run it normally with `python3 test.py`. Would I need to change anything in the installation?

Just for reference, this is the code I wanted to use:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
tz_NY = pytz.timezone('America/New_York') 
datetime_NY = datetime.now(tz_NY)
print("NY time:", datetime_NY.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried using `pip3 install pytz`  or `python3 -m pip install pytz`?